# sql server missing from services ...unable to log into sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

From one day ...i m struggling to install the sql server 2012 express edition. kindly help me.

scenario

i downloaded as below :

step 1: download

[image]

step 2: installation

[image]

step 3: failed to log in

[image]

I Checked :

[image]

And also in services.msc --> i find only sql server vss writer

[image]

I think i have not installed the correct version.  kindly guide me which one i should download.

My system
32 bit os  + windows 7

Do i need to download this ?  SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe  [1 gb]

Kindly guide me so that i can install the same.

Answer (score 2):

You only downloaded (and installed) the Management Studio. That's the user interface only.
You need to download `SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe` now that you've installed the Management Studio.
The `SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe` installs both.

Comment: Ok i have started downloading these two...so i need to uninstall and install from start right....

Comment: @anurag I think you don't need to uninstall the SQL Management Studio. Once you download the SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe file, execute it to install the SQL Server instance. Once this is completed, run SQL Management Studio and you're able to connect to instance just installed.

Comment: Tried to install...but ended in error at last step.
Database engine services--> failed.
Sql server Replication--> failed.
Sql Browser--> failed.
sql writer succeeded
sql client connectivity succeeded
sql client connectivity SDK succeeded
tried two times...ended in same result :( I dont know where i am doing wrong...

Comment: It's usually a hassle-free process. Check if you have all necessary pre-requisites. Did it provide any reason for the failure? You may have to check the install logs (see Technet article [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702.aspx)). Also, since it's your 1st time installing SQL Server, you can search for a video tutorial online (in Youtube for example) and compare with what you did.

Comment: Also, since your question isn't about a programming related problem you could be better served asking this in [superuser](http://superuser.com/) or [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 1):

- SQLEXPRWT... is the sql server, and the management studio (WT = With Tools)
- SQLEXPR... is the sql server only (not the management studio or other services)
- SQLEXPR32... is [only the installer for 32-bit processors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2008/08/22/the-sql-express-2008-family-is-getting-bigger.aspx) (and only the sql server, not the management studio or other services)
- SQLEXPRADV... is the sql server, management studio, and Reporting and full text queries
- SQLManagementStudio... is the management studio only

The x86 and x64 suffixes denote the 32/64 bit version of sql server itself, not the installer.

At the time of writing, [wikipedia actually does a good job of describing this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express).

**Edit** And in fact, [the download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35579#) does an even better job of describing this under the Details section:

> Express with Tools (SQLEXPRWT)
>
> This package contains everything needed to install and configure SQL Server as a database server including the full version of SQL Server 2012 Management Studio with SP1. Choose either LocalDB or Express depending on your needs above.
>
> SQL Server Management Studio Express (SQLManagementStudio)
>
> This does not contain the database, but only the tools to manage SQL Server instances, including LocalDB, SQL Express, SQL Azure, full version of SQL Server 2012 Management Studio with SP1, etc. Use this if you already have the database and only need the management tools.